# I want to show in div the result from js

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I want to show in div or php the result from this example

```
<script>
   function dateformat()
   {
     var date = document.getElementById('date').value;
     date = moment(date).format('D MMMM YYYY');
     document.write(date)
     return false;
    }
</script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="return dateformat()" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
   <input type="date" name="date" id="date" >
   <input type="submit" onsubmit="return dateformat()">
</form>

<?php echo $_POST["date"]; ?>
```

How can I modify that code to use PHP with this format: DAY August 2019

```
<?php echo $_POST["date"]; ?>
```

Comment: if you want it to go to your php, you cannot stop the submission of the form, if you do you will have to use your js to put it onto the dom where you want it (rather than using your php)

Comment: What do you want to achieve with your `dateformat()` function? It always returns `false`, thus the form can never be submitted. Furthermore, PHP will render the HTML template right away and the POST parameter `date` will never be rendered like this.

Comment: Any real solution?

Comment: If your intention is not to submit the form but call the `dateformat()` instead then you can not use PHP. You may need to intimate yourself with a little bit of PHP and javascript.

Comment: How can I modify that code to use PHP with this format: DAY August 2019

Comment: @Toony, you can only do that by actually submitting the form and doing the data processing in PHP. You don't need javascript here.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do this with php? This requires you do do an extra server request and therefore causing more delay and a worse user experience then when you do it with Javascript and just alter an element.

Just adding an element to add the result and replace the `document.write(date)` by `document.getElementById("result").innerText = date;` does the trick perfectly.

```js
function dateformat() {
  var date = document.getElementById('date').value;
  date = moment(date).format('D MMMM YYYY');
  document.getElementById("result").innerText = date;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="return dateformat()" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
  <input type="date" name="date" id="date">
  <input type="submit" onsubmit="return dateformat()">
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: But how can I show the result in php like <?php echo $data; ?>. Because I want to use this in <textarea>. I can put only php there not html.

Comment: Send a request to your server (either with AJAX or Form Submit) with the date in your post data. However the most important question is WHY do you want to do this with php instead of javascript? What is your desired result? I got a feeling you don't need to request the server for this.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I use php because is a little bit easy to use.

Comment: PHP is good for server side coding, client side you can't use PHP. That's where you use Javascript. I recommend you to look into the client, server architecture of websites a bit. It's a bit to broad to answer as a question.